# How to calculate Levenshtein distance for every unique value using a for loop on a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to calculate Levenshtein distance in a dataframe using for loop.

```
df2_2=df2_1[['Concat','Count','ffour']].copy()
for a in df2_2['Concat'].unique():
    dw2_2=df2_2[df2_2['Concat']==a]
    vv = dw2_2.iloc[:, 1::2].values
    iRow, iCol = np.unravel_index(vv.argmax(), vv.shape)
    iCol = iCol * 2 + 1
    result = dw2_2.iloc[iRow, [0, iCol, iCol + 1]]
    b=result.copy()
    b=b.drop(labels=['Concat','Count'])
    print (b)
    b=b.astype(str)
    for a1 in df2_2['ffour'].unique():
        dw2_1=df2_2[df2_2['ffour']==a1]
        c= dw2_1['ffour'].copy()
        print (c)
        c=c.astype(str)
        for i in range (len(b)):
            distance=lev.distance(b,c)
            print (distance)
            ratio=lev.ratio(b,c)
            print (ratio)
```

i am getting an error in this

```
  File "<ipython-input-129-15900bf3d493>", line 17, in <module>
    distance=lev.distance(b,c)

TypeError: distance expected two Strings or two Unicodes
```

Need help on this.

Comment: `print(type(b), b)`; do the same for `c`.  The `print` command may be a blunt instrument for debugging and diagnosis, but it's quite effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will you suggest you to check the values of both `b` and `c`.
You can always just use `str(b)`, and `str(c)` and it might do the trick.
Like that:

```
distance=lev.distance(str(b),str(c))
```

Or you can just apply str()  on all the values in column `Concat`, to ensure that you will have only strings:

```
df2_2['Concat'] = df2_2['Concat'].map(lambda x: str(x))
```

Comment: It is working but the calulation is wrong. The column 'ffour' has the only 4 alpha numeric values so ideally the ratio should be 0,25,75 or 100 but i am getting values like 0.68. Can you please help on this

Comment: I don't know about the exact implementation of Levenshtein that you are using. There is plenty, and some of them have some variations...You can even implement your self https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/ 
like in the Url supplied. But 0.68 is pretty similar anyway and its hard to tell if it's ok or not without knowing what are the specific strings.

Comment: And **if** my answer did help your **original** question, I would appreciate if you will accept it as the answer.